# week function in proc sql

Tags: sql, sas, proc-sql, week-number

does any one know how to get weeknumber within sas proc sql ?

Answer (score 5):

Personally, I find it very hard to go past SAS's own, native `WEEK` function. It can be called from inside `proc sql`. Pass it a date value and it will give you the week number.

Comment: More on the week function can be found in the online docs: http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a003154994.htm

Answer (score 1):

Found this at the following link: http://www.hollandnumerics.co.uk/sasfaq/SASFAQ1.HTM

You can simulate a WEEK function by using the SAS functions INTCK and INTNX, e.g.:

```
DATA getweek;
   datevar=TODAY();
   week=INTCK('WEEK',
         INTNX('YEAR',datevar,0),
         datevar)+1;
RUN;
```